# Typescript - How to overide declaration in lib.d.ts

Tags: typescript, declare

Is there any way to override a var declaration in d.ts file?

```
initTaggingControls() {
    RTE.CanvasEvents.registerListener(RTE.CanvasEvents.editableRegionChangedEvent,     Function.createDelegate(null, this.onCustomTextChanged));
    RTE.CanvasEvents.registerListener(RTE.CanvasEvents.editableRegionBlurEvent,        Function.createDelegate(null, this.onCustomTextChanged));
    RTE.CanvasEvents.registerListener(RTE.CanvasEvents.editableRegionFocusEvent, Function.createDelegate(null, this.onCustomTextChanged));
}
```

RTE is part of SharePoint. Line `declare var RTE: any;` does the trick.
The problem lies in `Function.createDelegate` because I cannot declare, or redeclare it.

`Function` var is already declared in lib.d.ts. 
Is there any way to override var declaration to add custom methods?

`Function.createDelegate` is part of [Microsoft ajax Library.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd393582%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid no. e.g. the following is an error:

```
declare var String: any;
```

You can only add features to interfaces / modules. Variables definitions are closed.

I have a work item regarding the same : https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/917

Comment: If you want it. Vote for it :)